# Read Autofac xml configuration from DB and change it runtime

Tags: xml, configuration, inversion-of-control, autofac, code-injection

i'm having trouble searching for documentation and example reguarding autofac so i ask this here: i need to change at runtime the xml configuration that autofac accept to inject the implementations. I've thinked a scenario like this: a db field that is maintained and that decide how to configure Autofac. So my question is: is it possible to give to autofac that xml read from the db? can i change it at runtime in some way?

cheers all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherits from `ConfigurationModule` and define the `SectionHandler` property. Then you can register your custom module to load configuration from what you want.

```
    public class DbConfigurationModule : ConfigurationModule
    {
        public DbConfigurationModule()
        {
            using(XmlReader reader = /*getReaderFromDb*/)
            {
                this.SectionHandler = SectionHandler.Deserialize(reader); 
            }
        }
    }

    // Register your custom module
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(new DbConfigurationModule());
```

When you will want to reload your configuration, you will have to create a new `IContainer` (you can't unload a module) or register your module in a new `ILifetimescope` (which don't have the module loaded)